# Distance between equation and its reference number

Tags: eqnarray

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0} 
\section{Appendix}
\begin{frame}[label=C1]
\frametitle{Appendix}
\framesubtitle{Derivation of Eq. 7}
\begin{itemize}
\item In order to derive Eq. 7, let us re-write Eq. {\ref{6}} as follows:\medskip
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta _{i}=V_{i}^{F}-\left(1-p_{j}\right)f_{i}\left(L_{i}^{N}\right)-p_{i}f_{j}\left(  L_{j}^{N}\right)-v_{i}\left(T-L_{i}^{N}\right)
\begin{array}{c}
> \\ 
= \\ 
<%
\end{array}%
0
\end{eqnarray}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am wondering how I can leave some space between the 0 and the number of equation. Any hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: it is best not to use eqnarray at all (use the amsmath package instead) but if you do use it, only use it for multiline displays and always have two `&` on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `eqnarray`. It doesn't cooperate with `hyperref`, for instance.

If you remove all useless `\left` and `\right` and use the proper symbol for the triple relation, the equation will fit. Without the `itemize`, it fits even better.

For setting manually a tag, use `\tag`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}

\begin{frame}[label=C1]
\frametitle{Appendix}
\framesubtitle{Derivation of Eq. 7}
\begin{itemize}
\item In order to derive Eq. 7, let us re-write Eq. {\ref{6}} as follows:
\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\Delta _{i}=V_{i}^{F}-(1-p_{j})f_{i}(L_{i}^{N})-p_{i}f_{j}(L_{j}^{N})-v_{i}(T-L_{i}^{N})
\gtreqqless
0
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}

In order to derive Eq. 7, let us re-write Eq. {\ref{6}} as follows:
\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\Delta _{i}=V_{i}^{F}-(1-p_{j})f_{i}(L_{i}^{N})-p_{i}f_{j}(L_{j}^{N})-v_{i}(T-L_{i}^{N})
\gtreqqless
0
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]